# Bash script, killing a program (vim and atom->editor) within the running script

Tags: bash, shell, kill

Is there Any way to KILL/EXIT/CLOSE VI and ATOM from a running script
example script, test.sh:

EDITOR1=vi
EDITOR2=atom

$EDITOR1 helloWorld.txt
$EDITOR2 file1.txt

kill $EDITOR1
kill $EITOR2

Is there any NOT Set way to kill it, I mean with a variable fore example the Filename.

Comment: Please make your code more legible, I cannot fully understand what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pkill -f <filename>`, as shown below:

```
[fsilveir@fsilveir ~]$ ps -ef | grep vim
fsilveir 28867 28384  0 00:07 pts/5    00:00:00 vim foo.txt
fsilveir 28870 28456  0 00:07 pts/6    00:00:00 vim bar.txt
[fsilveir@fsilveir ~]$ 
[fsilveir@fsilveir ~]$ pkill -f bar.txt
[fsilveir@fsilveir ~]$ 
[fsilveir@fsilveir ~]$ ps -ef | grep vim
fsilveir 22344 11182  0 Mar18 pts/0    00:00:00 vim openfiles.py
fsilveir 28867 28384  0 00:07 pts/5    00:00:00 vim foo.txt
fsilveir 28958 28740  0 00:08 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto vim
[fsilveir@fsilveir ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

Kill a process by its name.

```
kill `pidof $EDITOR1`
```

Kill the last started process

```
vi file &
kill $!
```

&: start process in the background (for interactive command line sessions)
$!: saves pid of last executed process.

Comment: Does not seem to wrok

Answer (score 0):

kill won't work on any of the `EDITOR` variable because none of them are job id, kill only works on job ids or process ids. Running your above script does not place any of that commands in the background, once `EDITOR1` executes it blocks the entire program, nothing can run until that process ( created by the `$EDITOR1 filename` is killed. For you to achieve your desired goal you have to run them on the background using `&`, when you use `&` a JOB ID  will be created ( which increments ) at every call to `&`, you have to find a way to keep track of the JOB IDS . For example if you do `$EDITOR1 filename.txt &`; a job id of 1 is created, if you do `$EDITOR2 filename2.txt` a job id of 2 is created. Your case

```
EDITOR1=vi ; EDITOR2=atom

declare -a JOB_ID
declare -i JOB=0;

$EDITOR1 helloword.txt &;
JOB_ID+=( $(( ++JOB )) );
$EDITOR2 file1.txt;
JOB_ID+=( $(( ++JOB )) );

kill ${JOB_ID[0]}; // kills the first job
kill ${JOB_ID[1]}; // kills the second job
```

or you can use associative arrays

```
EDITOR1=vi ; EDITOR2=atom

declare -A JOB_ID
declare -I JOB=0;

$EDITOR1 helloword.txt &
JOB_ID[$EDITOR1]=$(( ++JOB ));

$EDITOR2 file1.txt &
JOB_ID[$EDITOR2]=$(( ++JOB ));

kill ${JOB_ID[$EDITOR1]}; // kills the first job
kill ${JOB_ID[$EDITOR2]}; // kills the second job
```

i have not tried any of this , but it's going to work

Comment: I dont know if i am doing something wrong, but none of these seem to work

Comment: ./killEd.sh: line 11: kill: (1) - Operation not permitted
./killEd.sh: line 12: kill: (2) - Operation not permitted
:~/Documents/coding/ios) Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.

Comment: this is what I get, and atom neither vi closes

Comment: sorry append % after kill . like this `kill %{then the variable name}`. vim requires an intereactive terminal to work so you can't place as a background job

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `killall` command, for example:

```
killall vim
killall atom
```